# \paracol environment: How to change from numeric to alpha enumeration?

Tags: numbering, paracol

Several generous tex.stacker's have helped me assemble the code below.
(h/t esp. @alchemist)

Having used only `enumitem` I'm confused which lines of code are controlling the enumeration.

Does `\paracol` generate the enumeration? Or possibly `\globalcounter*`? **Please explain how enumeration works in this code.**

For the final 2 "extra credit" questions I need to switch to alpha enumeration.This image shows the desired alpha enum style.

[image]

[image]

Thanks very much for your assistance.

Please note that the **extra credit problems begin on the 2nd page of the mwe.**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\pagestyle{head}
%Note: \& forces & to be literal character
\header{Algebra II: Unit 11 Quiz (Rational Expressions \& Equations)}
{}
{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    \noindent 
    
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    
\begin{questions}
        \fullwidth{\textbf{1-2 Simplify each expression.}}
        \begin{paracol}{2}
    
% Prob #1
\question $\dfrac{4x+12}{x^2+5x+6}$
            \\
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
                $\dfrac{4(x+3)}
                {(x+3)(x+2)}$
                \bigskip
            $\dfrac{4\cancel{(x+3)}}{\cancel{(x+3)}(x+2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{4}{x+2}}$
            \end{solutionorbox}
            
            \switchcolumn
            
% Prob #2
\question $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-4}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{(x+2)}(x+1)}{\cancel{(x+2)}(x-2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}}$
                \bigskip
            \end{solutionorbox}

%force new page
\switchcolumn*[\newpage]
   \fullwidth{\textbf{EXTRA CREDIT}}
 \bigskip
 
%Extra credit problems
 Divide and simiplify. Show all work clearly.
 \question 
 $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-4}$
            \bigskip
            \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
                $\dfrac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$
                \bigskip
                $\dfrac{\cancel{(x+2)}}{\cancel{(x+2)}(x-2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}}$
                \bigskip
            \end{solutionorbox}

    \end{paracol}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your images don’t show because they have become part of the code block. I am not sure whether that can be edited. So it’s better to upload them again and make sure the images stay out of the code block.

Comment: As for counters: the `paracol` manual advices to make those globally like you thought. The syntax is in the manual. There is also a command to end a page inside a `paracol` environment about halfway the manual. I can’t access those now, but will get back to you aa soon as I can on this.

Comment: Paracol should have no effect on enumerate, or \question, other than to change the column width.  This is simply an exam document class question.

Comment: @SiuslawMath Of course we can chat about the issues you're facing. I am not that familiar with the `exam class`, but whatever help I can provide, I will. I use the `xsim` package to create my exams by the way.

Comment: When I compile your example with my three lines using either LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX, I don't get any errors. So the cause may be found in some of the complete code you're using. Check specifically the labels of questions. There may be one or more duplicates present when you copied questions to alter only a few items.

Comment: Off topic: in the answer of the last (Extra Credits) an argument `(x+1)` is missing next to the canceled `(x+2)` .

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to your question on pages 39-40 of the `exam` class manual.

You need to enter the following lines prior to the *Extra Credit* question:

```
    \qformat{\textit{\thequestion}}   % not really needed, but emphasizes the capital A
    \setcounter{question}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Alph{question}}
```

The next question will start with the capital A.

Answer (score 0):

**(Partial) answer to the edited question**

Compare the `qformat{}` entries in the following code. To compile insert the code into your example.

```
    %force new page
    \switchcolumn*[\newpage]
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\textbf{EXTRA CREDIT:} \textit{Show all work clearly and completely to earn credits.}}
    \bigskip
    \switchcolumn
    
    \switchcolumn*
    \qformat{\textit{\thequestion}}   % not really needed, but emphasizes the capital A
    \setcounter{question}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Alph{question}}
    %Extra credit problems
    Divide and simiplify. Show all work clearly.
    \question 
    $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-4}$
    \bigskip
    \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
        $\dfrac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$
        \bigskip
        $\dfrac{\cancel{(x+2)}(x+1)}{\cancel{(x+2)}(x-2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}}$
        \bigskip
    \end{solutionorbox}
    
    \switchcolumn
    \qformat{\textbf{\thequestion})\hspace{5mm}}   % not really needed, but emphasizes the capital A
    \setcounter{question}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Alph{question}}
    %Extra credit problems
    Divide and simiplify. Show all work clearly.
    \question 
    $\dfrac{3x^2-13x-10}{x^2+2x-35} \div \dfrac{6x^2-11x-10}{6x-15}$
    \bigskip
    \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
        $\dfrac{(x-5)(3x+2)}{(x-5)(x+7)}\div\dfrac{(2x-5)(3x+2)}{3(2x-5)}$
        \bigskip
        $\dfrac{\cancel{(x-5)}(3x+2)}{\cancel{(x-5)}(x+7)}\div\dfrac{\cancel{(2x-5)}(3x+2)}{3\cancel{(2x-5)}}$
        \bigskip
        $\dfrac{\cancel{(3x+2)}}{(x+7)} \times \dfrac{3}{\cancel{(3x+2)}}  = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{3}{x+7}}$
        \bigskip
    \end{solutionorbox}
```

As you can see, the formatting of the label can be done with `\qformat`. However, I have no idea yet why the label no longer aligns with the question. It should still do that.

The `\parbox` is used to use the full page, which also means you have to re-align the columns. Hence the extra `\switchcolumns`.

Comment: Can you please explain the use of consecutive \switchcol commands: ```switchcolumn
    
    \switchcolumn*```  BTW: my wife's family is full Dutch (Friesland).

Comment: The `\parbox` is placed in the left column and extents over the right one. So any content in that column would be overwritten. Adding the first `\switchcolumn` aligns an empty right column to the one containing the `\parbox`. Then a new `\switchcolumn*`is issued to align the two questions in their proper places.

Comment: Off-topic...As a teacher for many years of adjudicated and "at-risk" teens, this comment in your profile really resonated with me: ```...and coach of (gifted) students and dropouts```.  Probably the reason you've been so generous with your time. I realize that you now work with high level university students while I passionately toil away with struggling Geometry and Alg II students. I'm wondering if you'd be willing to share any of your quizzes / tests / worksheets so I can learn a bit about the ```\xsim``` package you mentioned as alternative to ```\exam```.

Comment: Lol .. Although one might say I have a PhD degree and more, I worked with teenagers in middle and upper school. say from about 10 years upwards. My professional calling as a teacher went out to those pupils who were more or less condemned by other teachers. I didn't like that attitude and managed to prove them wrong. So I am a cast-out to the majority of teachers in the Dutch school system... Well. they think I am ... ;-D

Comment: Of course we can share exams and the way to stimulate students to access their talents both obvious and hidden so they can grow to their full innate potential. Just wonder how to share very personal information in a publicly orientated forum.